# No response while hitting Soap-Api in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, soap, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. Just trying to hit Soap-api (it's my first time in ionic). I have studied this following link and trying to hit api in same manner as described in below link.
Here is the link :-  https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap

Just trying to implement Login-Api in ionic.

Here is my sample code please have a look:-
In index.html i defined following lines :-

```html
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/soapclient.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.soap.js"></script>
```

**In app.js** :-

```html
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','starter.angularSoap'])

.state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
```

**In controller class** :-

```html
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService) {
 $scope.data = {};
  $scope.login = function() {
   LoginService.LoginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).then(function(response){
   $scope.response = response;
      alert(response);
  });
  }
})
```

**And in service.js I define** :-

```html
angular.module('starter.services', [])


.factory("LoginService", ['$soap',function($soap){
    var base_url ="http://192.168.0.17:90/index.php//api/v2_soap?wsdl=1";

    return {
     LoginUser: function(username, password){
            return $soap.post(base_url,"LoginUser", {apiUser: username, apiKey: password});
        }
    }
}])
```

**And In angular.soap.js** :-

```html
angular.module('starter.angularSoap', [])
```

Error i am getting :- http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.tNK8MFROASU/latest

I am not getting any response. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong? I will be greatly thankful for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: one thing that i can see is wrong, you are appending '//' in your base url after index.php shouldn't it be single '/'.